# Oracle Regexp Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanna extract the specific string from the string pattern. Using regular expression. But I find it only return the null value.

- original pattern: `<Information>Not readable</Information>`
- What I wanna extract from pattern: `Not readable`

Here's the SQL I used:

```
regexp_substr(tridata,'[a-zA-Z ]*(?=</Information>)')
```

But It only ends up returning `null` value.

I wanna know is there any problem with this query? or which manner can I use to extract the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support lookaround patterns in its regex engine. You can instead use a [subexpression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) (typically called a capture group in other regex engines) to extract a specific pattern:

```
select
    regexp_substr(
        '<Information>Not readable</Information>',
        '<Information>(.*?)</Information>',
        1, 1, '', 1)
from dual;
```

Demo: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/mk1rt44jwm58yev4rt8yr76s

Comment: But I would like to know what's the different between (.*?) and (.*) ?

Comment: `.*` is greedy, which means if you match `'abcc'` with `'a(.*)c'`, you get `'bc'` in the capture group. `.*?` on the other hand is non-greedy, so matching `'abcc'` with `'a(.*?)c'` yields `'b'` in the capture group, which is the more desired behavior for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(tridata,'(.*<Information>)(.+)(</Information>.*)','\2') AS tridata_new
  FROM t
```

where

- **\2** returns the **2**nd capture group from the match
- **(.+)** greedily(**`+`**) looks for any character(**`.`**) between *Information* tags

Answer (score 0):

This is one option, for sample data

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '<Information>Not readable</Information>' from dual)
```

query is

```
  3  select xmlquery('*/text()' passing xmltype(col) returning content) as result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Not readable

SQL>
```